# One-dimensional matrix (vector) as a miniature subscript

Tags: math-mode, vector

How do I produce this in LaTeX? [image] Unsurprisingly, this code doesn't work:

```
$$\tau_{\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 4\end{bmatrix}}$$
```

That code does move the vector down to become a subscript, but it does not miniaturise it, which is what I want.

Comment: Please add an MWE so that we can better understand replicate your problem to give you a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `bsmallmatrix` from `mathtools`, but changing notation would be better. The empty superscript will push down the subscript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

text $\tau^{}_{\begin{bsmallmatrix} 0 \\ 4 \end{bsmallmatrix}}$ text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Smaller version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{btinymatrix}{\left[\vcenter\bgroup
  \Let@\restore@math@cr\default@tag
  \baselineskip4\ex@ \lineskip1\ex@ \lineskiplimit\lineskip
  \ialign\bgroup\hfil$\m@th\scriptscriptstyle##$\hfil&&\thickspace\hfil
  $\m@th\scriptscriptstyle##$\hfil\crcr
}{%
  \crcr\egroup\egroup\right]%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

text $\tau^{}_{\begin{btinymatrix} 0 \\ 4 \end{btinymatrix}}$ text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work. With `resizebox` from `graphicx` package you could achieve this.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    $\tau_{\scalebox{.5}{$\begin{bmatrix}
        0\\4\end{bmatrix}$}}$
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: This does not make it miniature. I have the same code...

Comment: @Noam Hudson could you add an MWE please?

Comment: I have the same output. That is not what I want.

Comment: @NoamHudson Updated my answer